How do I write a syntax rule that includes optional whitespace?
I'm defining a new file type (*.new files) and its corresponding syntax file (vim/syntax/new.vim) and encountered a problem identifying class and function names.
Such *.new files use ClassName :: FunctionName. Notice there could be space before or after ::, but it is not required. In other words, in the below text
something else ClassName::FunctionName something else
something else ClassName :: FunctionName something else
something else ClassName  ::  FunctionName something else

, all ClassName and FunctionName are meant to be matched.
What do I put in my syntax/new.vim to identify the class names and function names?
I know
syn match                           MyHeader1 "^## .*" 
hi def link                         MyHeader1 GruvboxGreen

can identify lines starting with ##  as Header1 and assign GruvboxGreen style to it.
I tried and failed to identify className::functionName.
First in vim, I tried use:
/\v<\w+>\_s*\:\:

to match the class name, and
/\v\:\:\_s*<\w+>

to match the function name, both works.
Then in my syntax/new.vim I added
syn match                           MyClassName  "\v<\w+>\_s*\:\:"
hi def link                         MyClassName  GruvboxYellow

syn match                           MyFunctionName  "\v\:\:\_s*<\w+>"
"   Color 
hi def link                         MyFunctionName  GruvboxPurple

But there are two problems

Function Names are not matched.
Class Names are matched but :: are also highlighted

How should the syntax definition be improved?

The key part of the question is missing: what you actually tried.

@romainl nothing in our help center or meta (that I'm aware of) requires "what I tried" to be part of a good question. We do encourage including research and attempts in the question to improve its chances of getting a good answer, though, and not including research effort is listed as a reason to downvote. Of course voting is subjective… Anyway, if you think "include what you tried in the question" should be a rule here, take it to [meta]. Until then, please stop suggesting that it's required. This question can be answered as-is. [cont.]

[cont.] I will admit that a better answer could be given by teaching the OP where the failed attempts went wrong! But the core question of how to match the syntax question is answerable.

Well… How To Ask Questions The Smart Way supersedes all your help centers and metas. I will stop asking "what did you try" the day people stop treating this place as help desk and Vim as an unknowable black hole.

@romainl I've updated the post with my trial -- didn't include it as i was afraid that due to my limited vim knowledge I might be making mistakes blindly.

@romainl… take it to [meta]. I'm not aware of any consensus on this site that ESR's document, great as it is, should be taken as required for questions to be answered. Vote how you please! But don't suggest that it's required by a community that hasn't agreed on that.

Well, you seem confused. I didn't imply a consensus on this site and I didn't suggest that anything was required by/talk in the name of whatever imaginary community you are referring to. We have been there before and you don't seem to get it. Question was bad. Clarification was asked. OP fixed question. OP got satisfying answer. And all you did while others where busy solving problems, teaching and being constructive was inventing reasons to antagonize users. Resign.

In \v<\w+>\_s*\:\:, the colons are kept as part of the match, which is why they are highlighted like the class name.
The solution is to consume them during the matching but discard them afterwards. This is done with :help \ze:
syn match MyClassName "\v<\w+\ze\_s*\:\:"


There is another potential issue with your pattern: \_s* is generally used to match whitespace across line boundaries but it doesn't seem to fit with your sample. If the goal was to match "zero or more whitespace characters", then :help \s would be enough:
syn match MyClassName "\v<\w+\ze\s*\:\:"

